# jQuery Slide showing white space before transition is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a slide animation such that when a link is clicked, the current div hides and the hidden div appears. It seems to work fine however before the slide effect is complete, a white space appears. How can I avoid this white space such that the new div gives an illusion of sliding over without changing the position of the current divs.

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lu4pr3v/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".c-f").click(function() {
    $("#home-intro").hide();
    $("#cf-intro").show("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.left {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 90vh;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  height: 90vh;
}

.blue {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue !important;
  float: right;
  height: 90vh;
}

#cf-intro {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="home-intro">
  <div class="left">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a class="c-f" href="#">Some Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="cf-intro">
  <div class="left">
    some text more
  </div>
  <div class="right blue">
    Some even more text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to remove it from the document flow (via `position: absolute`, although `fixed` would also work) then animate its `right` CSS property, like so (see JavaScript comments for further explanation):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".c-f").click(function() {
        // set here and used by both functions to ensure the speed is always the same
        var animSpeed = "slow";

        // remove from document flow by setting "position: absolute"
        // (and ensure width is still 100%)
        $("#home-intro").css({
            position: "absolute",
            width: "100%"
        }).animate({
            // "push" it from the right
            right: "100%"
        }, animSpeed, function() {
            // hide once it's finished animating
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $("#cf-intro").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, animSpeed);
    });
});
```

```css
.left {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 90vh;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  height: 90vh;
}

.blue {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue !important;
  float: right;
  height: 90vh;
}

#cf-intro {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="home-intro">
  <div class="left">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a class="c-f" href="#">Some Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="cf-intro">
  <div class="left">
    some text more
  </div>
  <div class="right blue">
    Some even more text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. When i try this on my development server (not able to replicate the issue in the fiddle), the text  from cf-intro seems to go over the home-intro div and then the home-intro div suddenly disappears without the full cf-into div sliding

Comment: Is jQuery UI definitely present on your dev server? If the animation is missing then perhaps the library is, too.

Comment: it is definitely present.

Comment: I'm out of ideas in that case, sorry. Best of luck.